# How do I check enum property when the property is obtained from dynamic in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, enums, late-binding

Suppose I know that property `Color` of an object returns an enumeration that looks like this one:

```
enum ColorEnum {
   Red,
   Green,
   Blue
};
```

and I want to check that a specific object of unknown type (that I know has `Color` property) has `Color` set to `Red`. This is what I would do if I knew the object type:

```
ObjectType thatObject = obtainThatObject();
if( thatObject.Color == ColorEnum.Red ) {
   //blah
}
```

The problem is I don't have a reference to the assembly with `ColorEnum` and don't know the object type.

So instead I have the following setup:

```
dynamic thatObject = obtainThatObject();
```

and I cannot cast because I don't know the object type (and the enum type). How should I check the `Color`?

```
if( thatObject.Color.ToString() == "Red" ) {
    //blah
}
```

does work but it looks like the worst examples of cargo cult code I've seen in "The Daily WTF".

How do I do the check properly?

Comment: Do you know all possible values of the enum type in the side assembly and their numerical representations?

Comment: @YohDeadfall I'd rather not rely on that - noone knows what changes there.

Comment: do you have influence on the `obtainThatObject()` (and its return type)?

Comment: @stefankmitph No, I implement a callback and it has the parameter typed `object` and I have to deal with whatever the reference is bound to.

Comment: Would you prefer an exception if the value "Red" doesn't exist in the enum? I think that's probably as good as it could get?

Comment: @petelids I guess that's easy - `Debug.Assert( Enum.GetNames((Type)thatObject.Color.GetType()).Contains("Red"))` or something.

Comment: Out of interest, what is performing the check "properly"? If you must know if the object is precisely equal to the value `ColorEnum.Red`, you *must* have access to the definition of `ColorEnum` -- even if only dynamically. If you don't, any comparison to `"Red"` or the number `0` (which is the value of `ColorEnum.Red` in the above example) is prone to breaking if a non-`ColorEnum` happens to convert to `"Red"` or `ColorEnum` is changed so `Red` is no longer `0`. What exactly *are* you allowed to assume about the value and `ColorEnum`?

Comment: @JeroenMostert I guess we can assume here that the assembly name and the full enum name stay intact. Yes, checking that would require accessing the underlying `Type` object to verify its name. I don't think we can have clean code with dynamics and be sure that all the types match at the same type.

Comment: Well, you could check the `Type`, that's why I asked -- but it would be extremely roundabout, because if you can get down to checking that the type is exactly what you want, surely it's much easier to get a copy of the assembly so you know at compile time as well. It's hard to imagine having a dependency that specific that's still somehow "dynamic".  A trivial check if anything goes is `if (thatObject == 0)`, which works fine as long as I'm allowed to assume `ColorEnum` doesn't change. Likewise, `if ((KnownColorEnum) thatObject == KnownColorEnum.Red)` in the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the side assembly:

```
enum ColorEnum
{
    Red,
    Green,
    Blue
};
```

We know that Red exists, but nothing about other colors. So we redefine the enum in our assembly with known values only.

```
enum KnownColorEnum // in your assembly
{
    Red
};
```

Therefore we can perform parsing:

```
public static KnownColorEnum? GetKnownColor(object value)
{
    KnownColorEnum color;

    if (value != null && Enum.TryParse<KnownColorEnum>(value.ToString(), out color))
    { return color; }

    return null;
}
```

Examples:

```
// thatObject.Color == ColorEnum.Red
// or
// thatObject.Color == "Red"
if (GetKnowColor(thatObject.Color) == KnownColorEnum.Red) // true
{ }

// thatObject.Color == ColorEnum.Blue
if (GetKnowColor(thatObject.Color) == KnownColorEnum.Red) // false
{ }
```

Comment: This uses `ToString()` too. How is this better than just comparing the string literal?

Comment: It's better only because uses types. You can not use integer representations because ColorEnum can be changed and underlying values too. So only one way is to use the string coparison.

Comment: Yes, it uses `TryParse()` and extracts a parallel enum. Is that all the difference?

Comment: All difference is in the strong typing. The string comparison will be faster than the code in my answer. But if you use a color multiple times will be better to prefer a parallel enum stored in a strongly typed variable.

Comment: Yes, I see your point. This is indeed better for cases with reuse.

Answer (score 2):

How about parsing the Color property to your enum first

```
if ((ColorEnum) Enum.Parse(typeof (ColorEnum), thatObject.Color.ToString()) == ColorEnum.Red)
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: I don't have the reference to the assembly, otherwise I'd just cast to ColorEnum and compare.

Comment: But you can redefine enum in your assembly and use it :)

Comment: @YohDeadfall No, I cannot, because those will be two different enums.

Comment: ah, true - I overlooked that part about the reference

Comment: Using `Enum.Parse()` will throw an Exception if `thatObject.Color` contains an unknown value. `Enum.TryParse<T>()` should be used.

Answer (score 0):

One possible (unorthodox) way is: Force your dynamic object (whatever object it is) to be a ExpandoObject (with this extension method):

```
    public static dynamic ToDynamic(this object value)
    {
        IDictionary<string, object> expando = new ExpandoObject();

        foreach (PropertyDescriptor property in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(value.GetType()))
            expando.Add(property.Name, property.GetValue(value));

        return expando as ExpandoObject;
    }
```

Convert your obtainedObject:

```
var obtainedObject = (object)obtainThatObject();
var myexpando = obtainedObject.ToDynamic(); // now you have an ExpandoObject
```

So you can get the properties in an IDictionary

```
IDictionary<string, object> dictionary= (IDictionary<string, object>) myexpando;
if(dictionary.ContainsKey("Color"))
{
    var myValue = dictionary["Color"];
    string color = myValue.ToString();
    if(color == "Green")
    {
         // blah
    }
}
```

going this way you don't have to care what object it is...

Comment: Don't do `if(dictionary.ContainsKey("Color")) { var myValue = dictionary["Color"];`; instead use [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.TryGetValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013(v=vs.110).aspx).